# Advanced custom fields: reverse display order

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the following custom field now:

```
<?php query_posts(array('order' => 'DESC' ));  ?>

  <?php     while(has_sub_field("texts")){ if(get_row_layout() == "add_text"){  ?>


    <p class="druppel_txt"><?php the_sub_field('text'); ?></p>

    <?php } } ?>
```

In Advanced Custom Fields you can drag&drop each new row to a location, but since they start at the bottom and there are about a hundred on this page, I would like the order of the rows (sub_field) as displayed in the cms, to be reverse displayed on the front-end.

As you can see I have tried 'order' => DESC, but this has no effect. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You are right, but that did not work as well.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do it myself, change the above code with this:

```
$druppels = get_field(texts); 

 $druppels_reversed = array_reverse($druppels); 



foreach($druppels_reversed as $druppel) { ?>
 <p class="druppel_txt"><?php echo $druppel[text]; ?></p>
```